# row numbers for explicit rows in r

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, row-number

I need to get row numbers for explicit rows grouped over id. Let's say dataframe (df) looks like this:

```
 id  a   b 
 3   2   NA
 3   3   2
 3   10  NA
 3   21  0
 3   2   NA
 4   1   5
 4   1   0
 4   5   NA
```

I need to create one more column that would give row number sequence excluding the case where `b == 0`.

desired output:

```
 id  a   b   row
 3   2   NA   1
 3   3   2    2
 3   10  NA   3
 3   21  0    -
 3   2   NA   4
 4   1   5    1
 4   1   0    -
 4   5   NA   2
```

I used dplyr but not able to achieve the same,
My code:

```
df <- df %>%
       group_by(id) %>%
       mutate(row = row_number(id[b != 0]))
```

Please suggest some better way to do this.

Comment: `mutate(row = ifelse(!is.na(b), NA, cumsum(is.na(b))))`

Comment: Or `mutate(row = replace(cumsum(is.na(b)), b == 0, "-"))` but you should note that by placing a "-" into a numeric column, it will be coerced to character.

Comment: updated question, there might be some numerical value in b

Comment: Try with `cumsum(b != 0 | is.na(b))` instead then

Comment: @Khashaa your code does not produce the desired output.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would propose using the `data.table` package for its nice capability in operating on subsets and thus avoiding inefficient operations such as `ifelse` or evaluation the whole data set. Also, it is better to keep you vector in numeric class (for future operations), thus `NA` will be probably preferable to `-` (character), here's a possible solution

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[is.na(b) | b != 0, row := seq_len(.N), by = id]
#    id  a  b row
# 1:  3  2 NA   1
# 2:  3  3  2   2
# 3:  3 10 NA   3
# 4:  3 21  0  NA
# 5:  3  2 NA   4
# 6:  4  1  5   1
# 7:  4  1  0  NA
# 8:  4  5 NA   2
```

---

The idea here is to operate only on the rows where `is.na(b) | b != 0` and generate a sequence of each group size (`.N`) while updating `row` *in place* (using `:=`). All the rest of the rows will be assigned with `NA`s by default.

Comment: Argh, back to the old `==` vs `%in%` vs join distinctions http://stackoverflow.com/a/16222108 (related to Arun's suggestion in the comment above).