# Why does filtering with != in dplyr (same in data.table) drops rows with NA

Tags: r, database, dplyr

```
library(dplyr)
dt <- data.frame(A=c(1,2), B=c(NA,5))
tbl_df(dt) %>% filter(A!=B)
```

I could get it that it can't compare > pr <. But it's kinda more intuitive to think NA is not equal to other values except other NA. Is there a work around to this?

Comment: I guess the `filter` by default removes the NA rows.  One option might be `tbl_df(dt) %>% filter(A!=B| is.na(B))`

Comment: Because  `1 != NA` returns `NA`, not `TRUE`. To get a comparison with `NA` to return `TRUE`, you need `is.na`.

Comment: Kind of related to my old question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/16221742/ The suggestion there was `tbl_df(dt) %>% filter(!(A %in% B))`. If you think that's adequate (and I do), we can close your question with a link to mine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option would be to create another condition with `is.na`

```
tbl_df(dt) %>% 
      filter(A!=B| rowSums(is.na(.))>0)
#      A     B
#  <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1    NA
#2     2     5
```

If we look at the output from the comparison

```
with(dt, A!=B)
#[1]   NA TRUE
```

The first one returns `NA` as any comparison with `NA` returns `NA`.