# R: Need to check relationship between two variables across observations

Tags: r

Take a data frame like mtcars (but much bigger)

I would like to get a list of observations where the value of vs==1 and the value of am != 1. I don't want to have to scroll through a long list of 1s and zeros, but actually get a list of the observations. I could write a loop but is there a more R'ish way of answering that question?

#### Additional information

My actual example is looking for values in `first` which are `NA` while in `Grade` they are not `NA`. And this does not seem to work. Does `NA` get treated special?

```
x = subset(spreadgrades, first == NA & Grade == NA)
```

Comment: TRy `library(dplyr); mtcars %>% filter(vs==1, am!=1)` or may be the question is not clear

Comment: @akrun No need for dplyr here. Direct indexing or using `subset` would be perfectly fine.

Comment: @Dason Yes, I was going to write `subset`, but then I thought the OP meant something els

Comment: I meant what @agerom wrote below.... Thanks!

Comment: To test `NA` values use `is.na()` method in R, not `==`

Answer (score 2):

Using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
mtcars<-data.table(mtcars)
mtcars[(vs==1 & am!=1),]

     mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
1: 21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
2: 18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
3: 24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1  0    4    2
4: 22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1  0    4    2
5: 19.2   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.30  1  0    4    4
6: 17.8   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.90  1  0    4    4
7: 21.5   4 120.1  97 3.70 2.465 20.01  1  0    3    1
```

Comment: Notice that `data.table` is unnecessary here. Within a `data.frame` you can also do `mtcars[(mtcars$vs==1 & mtcars$am!=1),]`

Comment: @gunbl4d3 I ain't using the "$" inside the syntax..

Comment: You should probably use an example containing NA in the `==` col just to confirm it does what OP wants. I have run into related issues before https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16221742/subsetting-a-data-table-using-some-non-na-excludes-na-too Oh, never mind, OP chose to talk about two different examples for some reason.

Comment: @Frank exaclty :) !

Answer (score 1):

Based on comments and answers, I settled on this:

```
subset(spreadgrades, is.na(first) & !is.na(Grade))
```

Comment: Good that you found an answer, but not cool to change your example after an answer is posted. Also, obviously you should post a reproducible example in the question, not just a single line of code...

Comment: yeah I know. I was trying to make it reproducible by using a well known data frame, but I didn't realize until the first answer, that NA was a key part of the problem that I was having.